# How to convert fixed margins in percent?

Tags: html, css

Here is a wrapper div with 450 px. If I set the height to 100vh, then the bottom margin of the title should adapt to the viewport.

```css
.title,
.subtitle {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 16%;
  height: 450px;
  margin-right: 42%;
  margin-left: 42%;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.title {
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="title">Title</div>
  <div class="subtitle">Subtitle</div>
</div>
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZNoZVm

Summary: The margins of the elements in wrapper should remain in proportion to the viewport.

Comment: look at `vh` unit

Comment: look at `vw` also

Answer (score 0):

I don't 100% understand (I know, I shouldn't be answering if I don't understand) but could it be that you're trying to say that you'd like the height of the wrapper to be the height of the viewport (screen height).

If that's the case then you're doing everything right, except...

On default the body has a margin of 8px. You simply have to remove that and you will get the result you're looking for.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

/* =================== */

.title,
.subtitle {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 16%;
  height: 100vh;
  margin-right: 42%;
  margin-left: 42%;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.title {
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="title">Title</div> 
  <div class="subtitle">Subtitle</div> 
</div>
```

(If you're wandering why you're still able to scroll, it's because "border" adds to the height (and width) so if your border-bottom is 3px and your height like 10px, you have an overall height of 13px)